# SASS (SCSS, Bourbon, Neat) Grid isn't working

Tags: css, sass, bourbon, neat

I am trying to use the [underscore](http://underscores.me/) base theme for wordpress with SASS, Bourbon and NEAT to create a nice flexible grid.

HTML:

```
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
    <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content">Skip to content</a>

    <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
    </header><!-- #masthead -->

    <div id="content" class="site-content">
    </div><!-- #content -->

    <footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
    </footer><!-- #colophon -->
</div>
```

SASS/Bourbon/Neat

```
#page {
    @include outer-container;

    #masthead   { @include span-columns(3); }
    #content    { @include span-columns(9); }
    @include omega();
    #colophon   { @include span-columns(12); }  
}
```

Created CSS:

```
#page {
  max-width: 68em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-right: 0;
}
#page::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
#page #masthead {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 2.35765%;
  width: 23.23176%;
}
#page #masthead:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
#page #content {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 2.35765%;
  width: 74.41059%;
}
#page #content:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
#page #colophon {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 2.35765%;
  width: 100%;
}
#page #colophon:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

Currently all the items (page, masthead, content) take up 100% width and stack on top of each other.

[image]

I would like to think I used it the right way, but I am sure I must have gone wrong as even the example of the neat page, outside of everything does not display correctly.

Any ideas?

---

This works, when you remove the skip link in the sassify, but it doesn't work in my local setup. Thanks katie, I will go on and investigate.

```
#page {
    @include outer-container;
    #masthead   { @include span-columns(2); }
    #content    { @include span-columns(9); }
    @include omega();
    #colophon   { @include span-columns(12); }  
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your results? http://sassmeister.com/gist/5ea39585a8a362ce71c8 What are you expecting to see that you're not seeing?

Comment: Added the information to the question, all the items take up 100% width and stack on each other.

Comment: Look at the Sassmeister link I made using your code - `#page` and `#content` aren't 100% wide, and "Skip to content" is next to the masthead. What are you **expecting to see**?

Comment: I feel really silly: I expected measthead to be a column aligned to the left, content to the right hand side of it and the colophon to be below both of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To end a "row" in Bourbon Neat, you have to include `omega()` in the last thing in that row; rather than in the outer container as in your code. Example:

```
#content { @include span-columns(9); @include omega(); }
```

You'll also need to handle your `skip-link` element - if it's not part of the grid system, it messes up the layout of the other elements. In the example below, I've hidden it with `display: none;`.

Here an updated full example: http://sassmeister.com/gist/5ea39585a8a362ce71c8

Comment: Funny enough my local vagrant dev-env didn't update after my computer went into hibernation. After a restart the modified code by KatieK works like a charm - thanks!